# In CSV files, problem with special character (") in a field

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem when i want separate two fields like them :

```
PRODUCTION,"CATEG"
```

I am testing it in this code :

```
import csv
with open(list_files[2]) as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read())
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
```

and I obtain :

```
['PRODUCTION,"CATEG"']
```

instead of

```
['PRODUCTION','"CATEG"']
```

any idea ?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: you don't need the sniffer since there's a comma: just do `reader = csv.reader(csvfile)`

Comment: sorry, it's in Python
Jean-François : I used it cause your solution doesnt work ;) . I know the comma is the default delimiter but in this case, it doesn't work. If you create a csv file with my example, does it works for you ?

Comment: can you try to print `[ord(x) for x in csvfile.read()]` ? looks that there are strange things in the file, that confuse the sniffer

Comment: if i add test=[ord(x) for x in csvfile.read()] i have nothing, test = []

Comment: I mean _after_ seeking back to rewind the file.

Comment: so by doing this ? 
    with open(list_files[2]) as csvfile:        
        test=[ord(x) for x in csvfile.read()]

Comment: yes, that works too

Comment: I obtain : [34,
 80,
 82,
 79,
 68,
 85,
 67,
 84,
 73,
 79,
 78,
 44,
 34,
 34,
 67,
 65,
 84,
 69,
 71,
 34,
 34,
 34,
 10]

Comment: your file contains extra quotes at start & end. So it's seen as one single field (34, .... 34). It doesn't match the input in your question.

Comment: 34,34 is " ... this is not surprising...
if I manually delete both " around CATEG, it works perfectly... I hope I dont have to write a code to delete the ", i cant believe there isnt a simple solution...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the sniffer makes a mistake. What do you get if you print `dialect` ?

Can you use

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect, delimiter=",")
```

instead ?

Comment: Well, this is what i tried first, but it doesnt work neither ;)

Comment: If i print dialect i have
<class 'csv.Sniffer.sniff.<locals>.dialect'>

Answer (score 0):

The [CSV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) states that to include a value that *may* have commas in it (it doesn't have to), you should surround the whole thing in quotes.

For example, the input `PRODUCTION,"foo,bar"` should be parsed as `['PRODUCTION', 'foo,bar']` not `['PRODUCTION', '"foo', 'bar"']`.

The CSV library that you are using is correctly parsing the file. To include a literal quote in the CSV file, you need to write two quote characters, so you'll have to change the input to be:

```
PRODUCTION,""CATEG""
```

Or manually parse it instead of parsing it as CSV.

Comment: You're right about the stripping of quotes, but with OP input, csv module returns `[['PRODUCTION', 'CATEG']]` on my machine. The question is why isn't it creating 2 fields.

Comment: I replied to your original comment - what do you mean it isn't creating two fields? I don't say anything mentioned in the question.

Comment: If I had an other " in my file I still have ['PRODUCTION,""CATEG""']

Comment: I seem to be missing something here - isn't that what you expect? The row should contain a list of the values in that row - in this case two values?

Comment: No I have only one value : PRODUCTION,""CATEG"" !

If i put whitespace to my last comment, it's : [ ' PRODUCTION , " " CATEG " " ']

Comment: I'm still don't understand, that's two values because you have a comma after "PRODUCTION" - the CSV library will split the line at this point. If you want that to be interpreted as a single value, you need to surround the whole thing in quotes: `"PRODUCTION,""CATEG"""` to stop it splitting on the comma.

Comment: no no, if i put it in a dataframe df and call df[0] I will not have PRODUCTION, i will have PRODUCTION,""CATEG""

Comment: I think your question doesn't include enough detail for someone to give an answer to whatever problem you're having. As it stands the code is working as one would expect, given the input you provide. Try and distil this to an example that still contains the parts you are having trouble with (eg your original question doesn't mention any dataframes) and lets others run the code and see the problem you are having.

Comment: Ok so I want to have :

import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(list_files[2],delimiter=',')
and then obtain 2 fields (df.production and df.categ)

Comment: Update the question, try not to just add more information to comments. In the question you are parsing using the built-in `csv` module - but your comment indicates you're now parsing with pandas, no one can help you if you've changed your code from what you're asking about. I don't know anything about pandas so I cannot help with this.

Comment: but you didnt resolve my initial problem ! I want to obtain [ ' PRODUCTION ' , ' "CATEG " ' ] and this is not the case.

Comment: I did not downvote your question. I have tried to help but do not know what your problem is.